# Hyperlinks all shown as one

Tags: html, css

I have 5 links that are images side by side but when i run my mouse over them its like its all one link. Please help.

I have updated my code to show the whole div. There is something thats making it happen in there.

The edits you told me works here but not on my website. Can you please help me find the error.

```css
/**********************************************************************************************************************************************Donation Boxes*/
.sponsors {
border: 1px solid transparent;
border-radius: 5px;
box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(32, 33, 36, 0.28);
color: #242527; 
font-family: Netflix Sans,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 17px;
font-weight: 300;

margin-bottom: 25px;
margin-top: 50px;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(32, 33, 36, 0.28);
padding: 15px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(32, 33, 36, 0.28);
width: 970x;
}

.sponsors img {
margin-right: 25px;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
width: 170px;
}

.sponsors-title a {
color: #da291c!important; 
font-family: Netflix Sans,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif!important;
font-size: 17px!important;
font-weight: 300!important;
line-height: 28px!important;
text-decoration: none!important;
}

.sponsors-title a:hover {
color: #242527!important; 
font-family: Netflix Sans,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif!important;
font-size: 17px!important;
font-weight: 300!important;
line-height: 28px!important;
text-decoration: none!important;
}

.sponsors-desc p {
color: #242527!important;
font-family: Netflix Sans,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif!important;
font-size: 16px!important;
font-weight: 300!important;
line-height: 28px!important;
}

.sponsors-links {margin-left: 10px!important;
text-align: right;
vertical-align: right;
width: 100%;
}

.sponsors-links a:hover {
text-decoration: none!important;
}

.sponsors-links img {
height: 25px;
margin-right: 10px;
width: 25px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="sponsors">
<table style="width:100%">
<tr>
<td valign="top">
<img src="https://wpadvancedads.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/300x250.png">
</td>
<td valign="top">
<div class="sponsors-title">
<a href="https://www.capebretoncares.com/">Hotels</a>
</div>
<div class="sponsors-desc">
<p>What’s happening to the ocean is a drag, but talking about it doesn’t have to be. Lonely Whale collaborates with organizations, influencers, and creatives to launch data-driven campaigns that speak to Gen Z, Millennials, and more. Join us.</p>
</div>
<div class="sponsors-links">
<a href="https://www.bigblueoceancleanup.org/" target="_blank">
<img class="social-icon" src="https://www.capebretoncares.com/images/sponsor-icons/icon_web.png">
</a>
<a href="https://www.bigblueoceancleanup.org/" target="_blank">
<img class="social-icon" src="https://www.capebretoncares.com/images/sponsor-icons/icon_twitter.png">
</a>
<a href="https://www.bigblueoceancleanup.org/" target="_blank">
<img class="social-icon" src="https://www.capebretoncares.com/images/sponsor-icons/icon_insta.png">
</a>
<a href="https://www.bigblueoceancleanup.org/" target="_blank">
<img class="social-icon" src="https://www.capebretoncares.com/images/sponsor-icons/icon_facebook.png">
</a>
<a href="https://www.bigblueoceancleanup.org/" target="_blank">
<img class="social-icon" src="https://www.capebretoncares.com/images/sponsor-icons/icon_youtube.png">
</a>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: That is just until i put the new links in. If you run your mouse over the icons they seem like there all connected

Comment: Please visit the live demo page https://www.capebretoncares.com/p/sponsors/ run your mouse slowly across the icons there is no breaks.

Comment: So you mean that the mouse cursor changes to pointer and remains a pointer in the spaces between the links?? and you want to change it??

Comment: Yes i do please

Comment: @Mech The link's width is too big. You just need to limit that width.

Comment: How do i do that.

Comment: @Mech can you look at my updated post please.

Comment: @Mech if i take <div class="sponsors"> out of the code it works fine.

Comment: @Mech is there a way to make it work on my webpage.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220603/discussion-between-laurie-williams-and-mech).

Comment: @LaurieWilliams Please be sure to select an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `display` property of the links to `inline-block`. It might also make more sense to apply the margin to the links instead of the images.

```css
.sponsors-links a {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.sponsors-links a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.sponsors-links img {
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sponsors-links">
<a href="https://www.bigblueoceancleanup.org/" target="_blank">
<img class="social-icon" src="https://www.capebretoncares.com/images/sponsor-icons/icon_web.png">
</a>
<a href="https://www.bigblueoceancleanup.org/" target="_blank">
<img class="social-icon" src="https://www.capebretoncares.com/images/sponsor-icons/icon_twitter.png">
</a>
<a href="https://www.bigblueoceancleanup.org/" target="_blank">
<img class="social-icon" src="https://www.capebretoncares.com/images/sponsor-icons/icon_insta.png">
</a>
<a href="https://www.bigblueoceancleanup.org/" target="_blank">
<img class="social-icon" src="https://www.capebretoncares.com/images/sponsor-icons/icon_facebook.png">
</a>
<a href="https://www.bigblueoceancleanup.org/" target="_blank">
<img class="social-icon" src="https://www.capebretoncares.com/images/sponsor-icons/icon_youtube.png">
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: It is still the same.

Comment: yes!! you can go to the link by clicking in the spaces also.

Comment: How can I stop that from happening

Comment: There has to be something in my css doing it because it works here but not on my site.

Comment: @LaurieWilliams check the spelling of the class in css file and html file

Answer (score 0):

You can do this also and change the margins according to your need.

```css
.sponsors-links {
    display: flex;
}

.sponsors-links a {
    margin:10px}

.sponsors-links a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.sponsors-links img {
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sponsors-links">
<a href="https://www.bigblueoceancleanup.org/" target="_blank">
<img class="social-icon" src="https://www.capebretoncares.com/images/sponsor-icons/icon_web.png">
</a>
<a href="https://www.bigblueoceancleanup.org/" target="_blank">
<img class="social-icon" src="https://www.capebretoncares.com/images/sponsor-icons/icon_twitter.png">
</a>
<a href="https://www.bigblueoceancleanup.org/" target="_blank">
<img class="social-icon" src="https://www.capebretoncares.com/images/sponsor-icons/icon_insta.png">
</a>
<a href="https://www.bigblueoceancleanup.org/" target="_blank">
<img class="social-icon" src="https://www.capebretoncares.com/images/sponsor-icons/icon_facebook.png">
</a>
<a href="https://www.bigblueoceancleanup.org/" target="_blank">
<img class="social-icon" src="https://www.capebretoncares.com/images/sponsor-icons/icon_youtube.png">
</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is that you are adding space within the `<a></a>` tags by using `margin-right`. If it is inside of `<a></a>` then it will be part of the link.

To overcome this, I've added `<span class="divider"></span>` to be added after each link which gives you the ability to customize the amount of white space after the link without being part of the link itself.

I have also removed the margins within your `img` css.

```css
/**********************************************************************************************************************************************Donation Boxes*/

.sponsors {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(32, 33, 36, 0.28);
  color: #242527;
  font-family: Netflix Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(32, 33, 36, 0.28);
  padding: 15px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(32, 33, 36, 0.28);
  width: 970x;
}

.sponsors img {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.sponsors-title a {
  color: #da291c!important;
  font-family: Netflix Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif!important;
  font-size: 17px!important;
  font-weight: 300!important;
  line-height: 28px!important;
  text-decoration: none!important;
}

.sponsors-title a:hover {
  color: #242527!important;
  font-family: Netflix Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif!important;
  font-size: 17px!important;
  font-weight: 300!important;
  line-height: 28px!important;
  text-decoration: none!important;
}

.sponsors-desc p {
  color: #242527!important;
  font-family: Netflix Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif!important;
  font-size: 16px!important;
  font-weight: 300!important;
  line-height: 28px!important;
}

.sponsors-links {
  margin-left: 10px!important;
  text-align: right;
  vertical-align: right;
  width: 100%;
}

.sponsors-links a:hover {
  text-decoration: none!important;
}

.sponsors-links img {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  text-decoration: none !important;
}

.sponsors-links a {
  text-decoration: none !important;
}

.divider {
  padding-right: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sponsors">
  <table style="">
    <tr>
      <td valign="top">
        <img src="https://wpadvancedads.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/300x250.png">
      </td>
      <td valign="top">
        <div class="sponsors-title">
          <a href="https://www.capebretoncares.com/">Hotels</a>
        </div>
        <div class="sponsors-desc">
          <p>What’s happening to the ocean is a drag, but talking about it doesn’t have to be. Lonely Whale collaborates with organizations, influencers, and creatives to launch data-driven campaigns that speak to Gen Z, Millennials, and more. Join us.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="sponsors-links">
          <a href="https://www.bigblueoceancleanup.org/" target="_blank">
            <img class="social-icon" src="https://www.capebretoncares.com/images/sponsor-icons/icon_web.png">
          </a><span class="divider"></span>
          <a href="https://www.bigblueoceancleanup.org/" target="_blank">
            <img class="social-icon" src="https://www.capebretoncares.com/images/sponsor-icons/icon_twitter.png">
          </a><span class="divider"></span>
          <a href="https://www.bigblueoceancleanup.org/" target="_blank">
            <img class="social-icon" src="https://www.capebretoncares.com/images/sponsor-icons/icon_insta.png">
          </a><span class="divider"></span>
          <a href="https://www.bigblueoceancleanup.org/" target="_blank">
            <img class="social-icon" src="https://www.capebretoncares.com/images/sponsor-icons/icon_facebook.png">
          </a><span class="divider"></span>
          <a href="https://www.bigblueoceancleanup.org/" target="_blank">
            <img class="social-icon" src="https://www.capebretoncares.com/images/sponsor-icons/icon_youtube.png">
          </a><span class="divider"></span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have same link `https://www.bigblueoceancleanup.org/` applied on all of the image icons for **web, twitter, insta, facebook, youtube**. That's why when you `hover` over them you are seeing the same link which is `https://www.bigblueoceancleanup.org/`.

Add the correct links for **web, twitter, insta, facebook, youtube icons** & your problem will get resolved.

**See what you have added in your code, all icons have same link:**

```
<div class="sponsors-links">
    <a href="https://www.bigblueoceancleanup.org/" target="_blank">
        <img class="social-icon" src="https://www.capebretoncares.com/images/sponsor-icons/icon_web.png">
    </a>
    <a href="https://www.bigblueoceancleanup.org/" target="_blank">
        <img class="social-icon" src="https://www.capebretoncares.com/images/sponsor-icons/icon_twitter.png">
    </a>
    <a href="https://www.bigblueoceancleanup.org/" target="_blank">
        <img class="social-icon" src="https://www.capebretoncares.com/images/sponsor-icons/icon_insta.png">
    </a>
    <a href="https://www.bigblueoceancleanup.org/" target="_blank">
        <img class="social-icon" src="https://www.capebretoncares.com/images/sponsor-icons/icon_facebook.png">
    </a>
    <a href="https://www.bigblueoceancleanup.org/" target="_blank">
        <img class="social-icon" src="https://www.capebretoncares.com/images/sponsor-icons/icon_youtube.png">
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: I am not talking about seeing the same link. Its all the icons connect as one.

Comment: @LaurieWilliams This is what i understood from your question. Put a clear question with a sample output then may be someone can help you.